# Read command result error (fgets)

Tags: fgets

I wrote a simple cocoa app with a button.

When the button is clicked, a timer is triggered:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(readCommandResult:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

And here is the timer:

```
-(void)readCommandResult:(NSTimer *) timer
{
char ps_cmd[256] = {"ls"};
BOOL isFgetsOK = NO;

FILE *fp = popen(ps_cmd, "r"); 
if (fp) {
    char line[4096];
    while (line == fgets(line, 4096, fp)) {

        isFgetsOK = YES;
    }
    pclose(fp);
}
else {

    NSLog(@"popen error");
}   
if (!isFgetsOK) {
    NSLog(@"fgets error");
}
}
```

When I run the app, I will get the "fgets error" sometimes,
it seems like "line == fgets(line, 4096, fp))" is failed but I
don't why?

Could some please explain it to me why I get a "fgets error" here
sometimes randomly??

PS:
I tried to change the comamnd (from "ls" to "ps");
In the terminal, I got the result:

```
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
```

And the new code in the timer:

```
 -(void)readCommandResult:(NSTimer *) timer
    {
    char ps_cmd[256] = {"ps"};
    BOOL isFgetsOK = NO;

    FILE *fp = popen(ps_cmd, "r"); 
    if (fp) {
        char line[4096];
        while (line == fgets(line, 4096, fp)) {

                        NSLog(@"length:%d line:%s", strlen(line), line);
            isFgetsOK = YES;
        }
        pclose(fp);
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"popen error");
    }   
    if (!isFgetsOK) {
        NSLog(@"fgets error");
    }
    }
```

And I got the log:

```
19:56:23.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:23.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:24.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:24.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:25.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:25.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:26.780 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:26.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:27.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] fgets error
19:56:28.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:28.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:29.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:29.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:30.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:30.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:31.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:31.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:32.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:32.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:33.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:33.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:34.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:34.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:35.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:35.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:36.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:36.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:37.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:37.783 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:38.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:38.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:39.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:39.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:40.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:40.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:41.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] fgets error
19:56:42.783 TopDemo[856:a0f] fgets error
19:56:43.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] fgets error
19:56:44.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:44.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:45.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:45.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:46.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] fgets error
19:56:47.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:47.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
19:56:48.781 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:29 line:  PID TTY           TIME CMD
19:56:48.782 TopDemo[856:a0f] length:31 line:  744 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
```

And I tried to run the app several times and the "fgets error" come out
randomly...

Comment: you need to put your log call outside of the while loop. We know the while loop isn't entered on a problem, otherwise `isFgetsOK` would be modified. I wanted to see what output you got when fgets wasn't returning the pointer that was passed to it. Just to be safe, you should also probably initialize line to ""...

Comment: Also, `errno` would be a nice thing to check...

Answer (score 0):

From the manpage (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fgets.html):

> Upon successful completion, fgets()
>   returns s. If the stream is at
>   end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator
>   for the stream is set and fgets()
>   returns a null pointer. If a read
>   error occurs, the error indicator for
>   the stream is set, fgets() returns a
>   null pointer and sets errno to
>   indicate the error.

<strike>On end of file, it returns null, and if the file is less than 4096 characters, it would hit EOF on the first iteration, so `isFgetsOK = YES;` would not be reached.</strike>

Sorry, misinterpreted... It returns null if the stream is **at** EOF when fgets is called, not if it reaches EOF during the call... ^^;

Comment: Thanks for answering but when I run the app, the result of "ls" is awayls the same, then why it still get that error sometimes?

Comment: @supersurabbit, Are you sure it's always the same? At any rate, it would be due to the while condition failing, so why don't you add a more descriptive error message, maybe including `strlen(line)` or adding a counter to count how many times the loop iterates?